# Golang append an item to a slice

Tags: go

Why does the slice `a` remain the same? Does `append()` generate a new slice?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var a = make([]int, 7, 8)

func Test(slice []int) {
    slice = append(slice, 100)
    fmt.Println(slice)
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 7; i++ {
        a[i] = i
    }

    Test(a)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Output:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 100]
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

Comment: This code will explain what's happening: [https://play.golang.org/p/eJYq65jeqwn](https://play.golang.org/p/eJYq65jeqwn). func Test(slice []int), receives a copy of slice value of a. And it is pointing to the same array as a pointing.

Comment: slice is a `struct` that passed by value, not by reference or pointer. The equal sign just breaks the chain of those `slice`s in `Test`.

Comment: As in all languages in the C family, everything in Go is [https://golang.org/doc/faq#pass_by_value](passed by value). That means for slice type, passing a pointer value makes a copy of the pointer, but not the data it points to.  it's especially important to return the slice, since when it reallocates the resulting slice describes a completely different array.

Answer (score 70):

In your example the `slice` argument of the `Test` function receives *a copy* of the variable `a` in the caller's scope.

Since a slice variable holds a "slice descriptor" which merely *references* an underlying array, in your `Test` function you modify the slice descriptor held in the `slice` variable several times in a row, but this does not affect the caller and its `a` variable.

<s>Inside the `Test` function, the first `append` reallocates the backing array under the `slice` variable, copies its original contents over, appends `100` to it, and that's what you're observing.  Upon exiting from `Test`, the `slice` variable goes out of scope and so does the (new) underlying array that slice references.</s> ([Jeff Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/569124/jeff-lee) is correct about that it's not what really happens, so the updated version follows; as he correctly states, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20222209/720999) is correct, if maybe a bit too terse.)

Outside the `Test` function, a slice of length 7 and capacity 8 is allocated, and its 7 elements filled.
Inside the `Test` function, the first `append` sees the that the slice's capacity is still one element larger than its length — in other words, there is room for one more element to add without reallocation.
So it "eats up" that remaining element and places `100` to it, after which it adjusts the length in the copy of the slice descriptor to become equal to the slice's capaticy.
This does not affect the slice descriptor's in the caller's scope.

And that's what you're observing.  Upon exiting from `Test`, the `slice` variable goes out of scope and so does the (new) underlying array that slice references.

If you want to make `Test` behave like `append`, *you have to return the new slice from it* — just like `append` does — and require the callers of `Test` to use it in the same way they would use `append`:

```
func Test(slice []int) []int {
    slice = append(slice, 100)

    fmt.Println(slice)

    return slice
}

a = Test(a)
```

Please read [this article](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) thoroughly as it basically shows you how to implement `append` by hand, after explaining how slices are working internally.  Then read [this](http://blog.golang.org/slices).

Comment: I actually think that this description is incorrect in subtle ways. @doun's answer below is actually a more correct representation of what's going on internally: the `append` in `Test` does not reallocate any memory, because the original allocation of the array backing slice `a` can still fit a single additional item. In other words, as this program is written, the return value of `Test(a)` and `a` are different slice headers with different lengths, but they point to the exact same underlying array. Printing `fmt.Println(a[:cap(a)]` as the last line of the `main` function makes this clear.

Comment: This statement is WRONG; "In your example the slice argument of the Test function receives a copy of the variable a in the caller's scope". As it mentioned in [Go slice usage](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals), func receives a pointer. Try changing `slice = append(slice, 100)` -> `slice[1] = 13`. You'll get printed `[0 13 2 3 4 5 6]` twice. @kostix can you explain that?. Refer - https://play.golang.org/p/QKRnl5CTcM1

Comment: @gihanchanuka, in the case of `func Test(slice []int)`, the function does not receive "a pointer". In Go, everything, ever, is passed by value; just some types happen to have pointer representation or _contain_ pointers. Slices in Go are of that latter variety: any slice value is a struct of three fields, one of which is, indeed, a pointer to the memory block holding the slice's elements.

Comment: @gihanchanuka, now the built-in `append` function takes a slice value and returns a slice value. In both cases it's that three-field struct, which is _copied_ on input and on output (into the `append`'s stack frame, and then outside of it). Now if `append` had to reallocate the slice's storage to make room for the data to be appended, the slice value it returned contains a pointer _different_ from the one in the input slice value. And this happens only if `append` had to reallocate, and does not happen otherwise (the underlying array had unused space). That's the gist of "the problem".

Comment: @kostix I got it  "+1", Thanks! This code will explain what's happening: [https://play.golang.org/p/zJT7CW-pfp8](https://play.golang.org/p/zJT7CW-pfp8). `func Test(slice []int)`, receives a copy of slice value of `a`. And it is pointing to the same array as `a` pointing. I can't edit my above comment and removing it will make confuse of this conversation.

Comment: Is there a reason why not all slices pointing to the old old array are updated to the new one?  Since Go is garbage collected, it should have a list of all pointers with some given value, or is this too simplified?

Comment: @fweth, it's a bit more compicated, on multiple levels, yes. First, I don't know of any non-toy language implmenetation which would keep a list of pointers to a given (shared) value for the purposes of doing GC; instead, the implementations typically employ either "reference counting"—each value carries a hidden counter with it which is incremented each time a value gets a new live reference to it, decremented each time such a reference is lost, and destroyed when the reference count drops from 1 to 0,—or some sort of "scanning" approach, when the GC starts with a set of "root" values…

Comment: @fweth,…known to be live, and then chases pointers kept in these values to mark the referred in such way values as live; all values not marked in this way after the scan is completed are considered dead and are then collected. Both contemporary implementations of Go implement the latter approach (known as "tri-color mark-and-sweep" algotythm).

Comment: @fweth, Second, implementation of slices in Go actually balances between a set of mutually-exclusive requirements. It's best to start with understanding that a slice primarily is _a view_ of an array—a sort of window through which you may conveniently access only a single (contiguous) subset of the underlying array's memory, without expliticly carrying around a pointer and a length (or an offset and a length)—as you'd typically do in languages like C. …

Comment: @fweth, …That's why all slices created off the same backing array (or through other slices which are views to the same array) share the same array (are views into the same data. But then it's also useful to have in a language some means to easily manage a growable chunk of memory—and growable in some simple way, so as to not write many conditional statements and explicitly calling "reallocation" functions. This approach was integrated into the implementation of slices, too: if you `append` to a slice, and there's no room for more data in its backing array,…

Comment: @fweth, …the array is _reallocated_ in a way so that it holds both the old data and the appended data. This makes other slices which still reference the original array unaffected. Why is that? One possible reason is that you can easily take an address of the backing array through a slice: if `s` is a slice, `&s[0]` is the address of the first element in the slice's backing array, and also the address of the array itself. If we were to somehow update all the slices which reference an original backing array when we've replaced it through `append`ing to some other slice, we could do nothing to…

Comment: @fweth …the outstanding pointers to the original backing array possibly obtained via those other slices. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @kostix hey thanks so much for the clarifications!  Yes, everything makes sense now.  I really like the way they implemented slices, I think NumPy did it similarly.

Comment: @JeffLee, you're correct and I'm sorry for neglecting your suggestion for so long. Updated, thanks.

Answer (score 42):

Typical `append` usage is

```
a = append(a, x)
```

because `append` may either modify its argument in-place *or* return a copy of its argument with an additional entry, depending on the size and capacity of its input. Using a slice that was previously appended to may give unexpected results, e.g.

```
a := []int{1,2,3}
a = append(a, 4)
fmt.Println(a)
append(a[:3], 5)
fmt.Println(a)
```

may print

```
[1 2 3 4]
[1 2 3 5]
```

Comment: Thanks, larsmans, I modified some code. "make" would give a enough capacity. The result is the same and I'm sill confused.

Comment: This needs to be `_ = append(a[:3], 5)` to compile now

Comment: `append(a[:3], 5)` is same as `a[3] = 5` in the following hack. I guess this is an example where unexpected surprise happens.

Answer (score 14):

In order to make your code work without having to return the slice from Test, you can pass a pointer like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var a = make([]int, 7, 8)

func Test(slice *[]int) {
    *slice = append(*slice, 100)

    fmt.Println(*slice)
}

func main() {

    for i := 0; i < 7; i++ {
        a[i] = i
    }

    Test(&a)

    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

NOTICE that *append* generates a new slice if *cap* is not sufficient. @kostix's answer is correct, or you can pass *slice* argument by pointer!

Comment: You're correct about pointers but I have decidedly not mentioned them because the slices were invented mostly to free the programmers from dealing with pointers to arrays.  In a reference implementation (from Go), a slice variable holds a pointer and two integers, so copying it is cheap and that's why `slice = append(slice, a, b, c)` is idiomatic, not passing a slice variable by pointer and modifying it "in place" so that the caller sees the change.

Comment: @kostix You're right, the purpose of the codes should be explicit. But I think the whole story is just about passing a value storing a pointer and passing a pointer pointing to a pointer. If we modify the reference, both can work, but if we replace the reference, the first one loses effects. The programmer should know what he is doing.

Answer (score 5):

Try this, which I think makes it clear. the underlying array is changed but our slice is not, `print` just prints `len()` chars, by another slice to the `cap()`, you can see the changed array:

```
func main() {

  for i := 0; i < 7; i++ {
      a[i] = i
  }

  Test(a)

  fmt.Println(a) // prints [0..6]
  fmt.Println(a[:cap(a)] // prints [0..6,100]
}
```

Comment: so 'a' and 'a[:cap(a)]' are different slice?

Comment: Yes,if you run the code you will find out that. because cap(a) is changed during the test(a) call

Answer (score 3):

Explanation (read inline comments):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var a = make([]int, 7, 8)
// A slice is a descriptor of an array segment. 
// It consists of a pointer to the array, the length of the segment, and its capacity (the maximum length of the segment).
// The length is the number of elements referred to by the slice.
// The capacity is the number of elements in the underlying array (beginning at the element referred to by the slice pointer).
// |-> Refer to: https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals -> "Slice internals" section

func Test(slice []int) {
    // slice receives a copy of slice `a` which point to the same array as slice `a`
    slice[6] = 10
    slice = append(slice, 100)
    // since `slice` capacity is 8 & length is 7, it can add 100 and make the length 8
    fmt.Println(slice, len(slice), cap(slice), " << Test 1")
    slice = append(slice, 200)
    // since `slice` capacity is 8 & length also 8, slice has to make a new slice 
    // - with double of size with point to new array (see Reference 1 below).
    // (I'm also confused, why not (n+1)*2=20). But make a new slice of 16 capacity).
    slice[6] = 13 // make sure, it's a new slice :)
    fmt.Println(slice, len(slice), cap(slice), " << Test 2")
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 7; i++ {
        a[i] = i
    }

    fmt.Println(a, len(a), cap(a))
    Test(a)
    fmt.Println(a, len(a), cap(a))
    fmt.Println(a[:cap(a)], len(a), cap(a))
    // fmt.Println(a[:cap(a)+1], len(a), cap(a)) -> this'll not work
}
```

Output:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6] 7 8
[0 1 2 3 4 5 10 100] 8 8  << Test 1
[0 1 2 3 4 5 13 100 200] 9 16  << Test 2
[0 1 2 3 4 5 10] 7 8
[0 1 2 3 4 5 10 100] 7 8
```

Reference 1: https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

```
func AppendByte(slice []byte, data ...byte) []byte {
    m := len(slice)
    n := m + len(data)
    if n > cap(slice) { // if necessary, reallocate
        // allocate double what's needed, for future growth.
        newSlice := make([]byte, (n+1)*2)
        copy(newSlice, slice)
        slice = newSlice
    }
    slice = slice[0:n]
    copy(slice[m:n], data)
    return slice
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Answer: append() will return new underlying array if **has no sufficient capacity**. In your example,

```golang
var a = make([]int, 7, 8)
```

You allocate a slice (length is 7)of an underlying array(capacity is 8) to `a`, then pass it to function as parameter `slice`. When `append()` is called, it found the `1` capacity, then just update the `slice`'s `len` from 7 to 8 and put the value 100 into that position.

The slice `a` is different to the slice `slice`, having different `len` property. **`len` and `cap` are the property of slice, not the underlying array**. For more details: [Are slices passed by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39993797/13760009).

Run the example below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var a = make([]int, 7, 8)

func Test(slice []int) {
    fmt.Printf("slice's address is %p\n", &slice)
    fmt.Println("slice: cap=",cap(slice),"len=",len(slice))
    slice = append(slice, 100)
    fmt.Println("slice: cap=",cap(slice),"len=",len(slice))
    fmt.Println(slice)
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 7; i++ {
        a[i] = i
    }
    fmt.Printf("a's address is %p\n", &a)
    fmt.Println("a: cap=",cap(a),"len=",len(a))
    Test(a)
    fmt.Println("a: cap=",cap(a),"len=",len(a))
    fmt.Println(a)
    fmt.Println(a[:8]) // manully extend a's len to cap of 8
}
```

Result is:

```
❯❯  Temp  17:33  go run .\test.go
a's address is 0x2cbfc0
a: cap= 8 len= 7
slice's address is 0xc000098060
slice: cap= 8 len= 7
slice: cap= 8 len= 8
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 100]
a: cap= 8 len= 7
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 100]
```

Answer (score 2):

> Go takes a more lean and lazy approach in doing this. It keeps
>   modifying the same underlying array until the capacity of a slice is
>   reached.

Ref: http://criticalindirection.com/2016/02/17/slice-with-a-pinch-of-salt/

Output of the example from the link explains the behavior of slices in Go.

**Creating slice a.**

```
Slice a len=7 cap=7 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

**Slice b refers to the 2, 3, 4 indices in slice a. Hence, the capacity is 5 (= 7-2).**

```
b := a[2:5]
Slice b len=3 cap=5 [0 0 0]
```

**Modifying slice b, also modifies a, since they are pointing to the same underlying array.**

```
b[0] = 9
Slice a len=7 cap=7 [0 0 9 0 0 0 0]
Slice b len=3 cap=5 [9 0 0]
```

**Appending 1 to slice b. Overwrites a.**

```
Slice a len=7 cap=7 [0 0 9 0 0 1 0]
Slice b len=4 cap=5 [9 0 0 1]
```

**Appending 2 to slice b. Overwrites a.**

```
Slice a len=7 cap=7 [0 0 9 0 0 1 2]
Slice b len=5 cap=5 [9 0 0 1 2]
```

**Appending 3 to slice b. Here, a new copy is made as the capacity is overloaded.**

```
Slice a len=7 cap=7 [0 0 9 0 0 1 2]
Slice b len=6 cap=12 [9 0 0 1 2 3]
```

**Verifying slices a and b point to different underlying arrays after the capacity-overload in the previous step.**

```
b[1] = 8
Slice a len=7 cap=7 [0 0 9 0 0 1 2]
Slice b len=6 cap=12 [9 8 0 1 2 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func a() {
    x := []int{}
    x = append(x, 0)
    x = append(x, 1)  // commonTags := labelsToTags(app.Labels)
    y := append(x, 2) // Tags: append(commonTags, labelsToTags(d.Labels)...)
    z := append(x, 3) // Tags: append(commonTags, labelsToTags(d.Labels)...)
    fmt.Println(y, z)
}

func b() {
    x := []int{}
    x = append(x, 0)
    x = append(x, 1)
    x = append(x, 2)  // commonTags := labelsToTags(app.Labels)
    y := append(x, 3) // Tags: append(commonTags, labelsToTags(d.Labels)...)
    z := append(x, 4) // Tags: append(commonTags, labelsToTags(d.Labels)...)
    fmt.Println(y, z)
}

func main() {
    a()
    b()
}

First guess could be

[0, 1, 2] [0, 1, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3] [0, 1, 2, 4]

but in fact it results in

[0, 1, 2] [0, 1, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 4] [0, 1, 2, 4]
```

[image]

[image]

More details see https://allegro.tech/2017/07/golang-slices-gotcha.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the original answer is not exactly correct. `append()` changed both the slices and the underlying array even though the underlying array is changed but still shared by both of the slices.

As specified by the Go Doc:

> A slice does not store any data, it just describes a section of an underlying array. [(Link)](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/8)

Slices are just wrapper values around arrays, meaning that they contain information about how they slice an underlying array which they use to store a set of data. Therefore, by default, a slice, when passed to another method, is actually passed by value, instead of reference/pointer even though they will still be using the same underlying array. Normally, arrays are also passed by value too, so I assume a slice points at an underlying array instead of store it as a value. Regarding your question, when you run passed your slice to the following function:

```
func Test(slice []int) {
    slice = append(slice, 100)
    fmt.Println(slice)
}
```

you actually passed a copy of your slice along with a pointer to the same underlying array.That means, the changes you did to the `slice` didn't affect the one in the `main` function. It is the slice itself which stores the information regarding how much of an array it slices and exposes to the public. Therefore, when you ran `append(slice, 1000)`, while expanding the underlying array, you also changed slicing information of `slice` too, which was kept private in your `Test()` function.

However, if you have changed your code as follows, it might have worked:

```
func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 7; i++ {
        a[i] = i
    }

    Test(a)
    fmt.Println(a[:cap(a)])
}
```

The reason is that you expanded `a` by saying `a[:cap(a)]` over its changed underlying array, changed by `Test()` function. As specified here:

> You can extend a slice's length by re-slicing it, provided it has sufficient capacity. [(Link)](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/11)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you use the `append()`, to add values to a Slice, it usually creates a new Slice and doesn't overwrite the original Slice.

Check the below code snippet

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    var ages = []int{3,6,8,1,9}

    fmt.Println(append(ages, 13))

    fmt.Println("Original Slice is still: ", ages)
}
```

If you need to overwrite the original Slice, you need to set the `append()` to the Slice name as below.

```
ages = append(ages, 12)
fmt.Println("Now original Slice is: ", ages)
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple.

1. If the capacity of the slice is **enough** to append, then just use the existing underlying array.
2. If the capacity of the slice is **not enough** to append, then create a **new** underlying array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice implementation of append for slices. I guess its similar to what is going on under the hood:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    slice1 := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
    slice2 := []int{55, 66, 77}
    fmt.Println(slice1)
    slice1 = Append(slice1, slice2...) // The '...' is essential!
    fmt.Println(slice1)
}

// Append ...
func Append(slice []int, items ...int) []int {
    for _, item := range items {
        slice = Extend(slice, item)
    }
    return slice
}

// Extend ...
func Extend(slice []int, element int) []int {
    n := len(slice)
    if n == cap(slice) {
        // Slice is full; must grow.
        // We double its size and add 1, so if the size is zero we still grow.
        newSlice := make([]int, len(slice), 2*len(slice)+1)
        copy(newSlice, slice)
        slice = newSlice
    }
    slice = slice[0 : n+1]
    slice[n] = element
    return slice
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Append to end of a slice, or create a new entry if slice is empty

```
// in := [][]int{{}}, in := [][]int{{1,3},{2,3}}
// addtoEndofSliceArray(in,10)
// out=[[10]], out=[[1,3],[2,3,10]]

func addtoEndofSliceArray(in [][]int,element int)(out [][]int){
    if len(in) >0 {
        k :=in[len(in)-1]
        k = append(k,element)
        in = in[:len(in)-1]
        in = append(in, k)
    }else{
        in = [][]int{{element}}
    }
    return in
}
```