# How to append a new element to a slice?

Tags: go

I tried to append a new element to a slice, just like appending a new element to a `list` in Python, but there is an error

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
    printSlice(s)

    s[len(s)] = 100
    printSlice(s)
}

func printSlice(s []int) {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", s)
}
```

and the output is

```
[2 3 5 7 11 13]

panic: runtime error: index out of range
```

How can I append a new element to a slice then?

Is it correct that `slice` in Go is the closet data type to `list` in Python?

Thanks.

Comment: https://gobyexample.com/slices

Comment: Also in [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#append), the [Go Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices) and in the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195296/golang-append-an-item-to-a-slice/20197469#20197469

Comment: Go slices are somewhat similar to python lists, but making assumptions based on that similarity is only going to cause confusion. Slices are very simple data structures, and it's better to just understand how they work to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

Appending in Go uses the builtin method [`append`](https://godoc.org/builtin#append). For example:

```go
s := []byte{1, 2, 3}
s = append(s, 4, 5, 6)
fmt.Println(s)
// Output: [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

You are correct, slices in Go are close to Python's list, and, in fact, many of the same indexing and slicing operations work on them.

When you do:

```go
s[len(s)] = 100
```

it panics because you cannot access a value beyond the length of the slice. There appears to be some confusion here, because in Python this works the exact same way. Attempting the above in Python (unless you've already expanded the list) will give:

```python
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```