# Can't understand the output of this program which uses slices and append

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    b := append(a[:3], 6, 7)
    fmt.Println("a is ", a)
    fmt.Println("b is ", b)
}
```

The above program prints

```
a is [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
b is [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
```

I understand the output of `b`. But why did slice `a` change?
Shouldn't `a[:3]` create a new anonymous slice and append 6,7 and return that to `b` instead of changing the original(`a`) slice? Why did append act on the original slice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang append an item to a slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195296/golang-append-an-item-to-a-slice)

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7 ff and https://blog.golang.org/slices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I slightly modified your program to make it more clear

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    b := a[:3] // Here Slicing does not copy the slice's data. It creates a new slice value that points to the original array
    b = append(b, 6, 7)
    fmt.Println("a is ", a)
    fmt.Println("b is ", b)
}
```

Refer this [Document](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro) for more reading !!

Comment: I request everyone to refer @sơn-xê-kô 's answer too, to understand a different nature of slice ,  that too relevant !!,

Answer (score 2):

NOTICE append function will create new slide if your slice is not sufficient (overflow). See difference between two examples:

```
func main() {
a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
b := append(a[:3], 6, 7) // add 2 elements, not overflow slice, doesnt create new slice
fmt.Println("a is ", a)
fmt.Println("b is ", b)
}
```

result

```
a is [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
b is [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
```

And

```
func main() {
a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
b := append(a[:3], 6, 7, 8) // add 3 elements, overflow slice, create new slice
fmt.Println("a is ", a)
fmt.Println("b is ", b)
}
```

Result

```
a is  [1 2 3 4 5]
b is  [1 2 3 6 7 8]
```