# How to add value to a slice of struct

Tags: go, struct, slice

I'm trying to add value to a slice of struct, I have the following struct:

```
type RelatedSearchItem struct {
    Title      string `json:"title"`
    Navigation string `json:"url"`
}
```

Now I create a slice of this struct :

```
relatedSearchItem := []models.RelatedSearchItem{}
```

And finally I add data to his fields :

```
    for i := 0; i < len(questions); i++ {
        relatedSearchItem[i].Title = questions[i]
        relatedSearchItem[i].Navigation = URL[i]
    }
```

But when I do this I'm out of the range of the slice so my app crash, how can I add data to this slice of struct and without a fixed length ?

I immediately think about `append` but here I'm not adding a slice to another I just want to build it with my data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang append an item to a slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195296/golang-append-an-item-to-a-slice)

Comment: Not exactly, because i want to add value to the field of a slice of struct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `append`:

```
for i := 0; i < len(questions); i++ {
  relatedSearchItems=append(relatedSearchItems, RelatedSearchItem{
          Title: questions[i],
          Navigation: URL[i],
         })
    }
```

Comment: Ah thank you, I didn't think to use append like this ! I was writing `relatedSearchItems = append(relatedSearchItems, relatedSearchItem[i].Title)` but that was not possible.